# Import with read_csv without guessing column types in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

Is there a way to use `read_csv` from the readr package and not guess the column type?

The function documentation tells about this argument: `guess_max = min(1000, n_max)`, which suggested to me that the standard value of `n_max` (which is `Inf`) is a viable option. It wasn't - it crashed the entire computer. No "R does not respond", no close the application, no moving mouse or any keyboard response - I had to restart using the power button.

I tried high values for `guess_max` which are below `Inf`, but the problem is that this makes everything slower the higher the value is. Right now I use the following code instead.

```
# how many rows?
rowsInFile <- read_csv(
        "sources/features.csv"
        , col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>%
    nrow()

# ...use that to not guess
df <- read_csv("sources/features.csv", guess_max = rowsInFile)
rm(rowsInFile)
```

I.e. I import the file to know how many rows and then "guess" up to that row. But I feel like there's gotta be a better way. Anyone got the idea that will sound obvious to me after I read it?

Comment: You should submit the crash as a bug in an issue on the `readr` github. Why not just make a full `cols()` spec for the CSV?  That will avoid the guess logic altogether.

Comment: That's true, but to be honest I am lazy and would really like to avoid writing lots of code. This is not about production code, so my preference is rather on coding faster than on performance.

Comment: Yes: *provide* the column types instead (`col_types` argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about performance try this combination of `length()` and `count.fields()`

`length(count.fields("sources/features.csv", skip = 1))`

`count.fields()` counts the number of fields, as separated by sep, in each of the lines of file read, so if we measure `length()` of that outcome, effectively we get the total number of rows in the file.

**Uninvited comment:** Correct me if I am wrong please, but from what I understand you are trying to take `guess_max` = `nrow` because you are assuming that if R has seen all the rows in a column then it is **not** guessing what is the class of that column?

I am not sure that is how it will work. Even if R looks at all the rows, it will still, in true sense of the word, *guess* what the class of that column.